# Explaining Ito formula to an analyst

Tags: analysis, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

From the point of view of analysis, what is Ito formula?
Is it an integral by substitution, or, a radon-nikodym derivative?

Define the probability space 
$$
\left(C\left(\Bbb R_+\right),\sigma\left(C\left(\Bbb R_+\right)\right),P\right),
$$
where $P$ is the standard Brownian motion measure.
Let $f(x)=x^2$, with Ito formula, I write
$$
\int_{C\left(\Bbb R_+\right)} f(X_t)dP(X)=\int_{C\left(\Bbb R_+\right)} \left\{\int_0^t 2X_sdX_s+t \right\} dP\left(X\right).
$$
The previous equation is my heuristic to explain Ito formula to an analyst.
This heuristic is itself inspired by the following heuristic which I once heard

> Ito formula is a way of expressing how the measure $P$ changes from $X_t$ to $f(X_t)$

Comment: I know it's not easy to enter on most keyboards, but his name is more correctly (Hepburn) romanized as "Itō" with a [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron) over the 'o' to indicate a long vowel. As a side note it's quite hard for non-native speakers to distinguish 'o' and 'ō' without practise. If you ever need a macron in a LaTeX paper you can use `\=` for it the same way you would for any other accent, i.e. `\=o` produces 'ō' - or one could use a unicode-aware TeX engine and just enter 'ō' directly.

Comment: @kahen When I look at other post, people write 'Ito' with no accent. I guess I can follow this practice, as effectively, the macron is hard to type. Thank you for telling me. I will correct it in my different posts.

Answer (score 4):

Itō formula has nothing to do with a probability measure. Let me qualify this statement. While stochastic integration ostensibly needs to be performed with the help of a probability measure, the *result* of stochastic integration is the same for all equivalent measures. In this sense stochastic integration, and therefore also the Itō formula, is a pathwise concept. It cannot be defined pathwise (in general) but the result is pathwise unique (up to indistinguishability). I hōpe this helps :-).

**Edit for Bananach:** The result of stochastic integration is the same under all equivalent measures: see Proposition 3.6.20 in
*Bichteler, Klaus*, [**Stochastic integration with jumps**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511549878), Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 89. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xiii, 501 p. (2002). [ZBL1002.60001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1002.60001).

Comment: Can you give a reference for the fact that the result is independent of measure changes? I never fully understood in which sense Ito's integral is a pathwise construction and in which sense it isn't

Comment: IOW, the formula in the question reads $$E(X_t^2)=2E\left(\int_0^tX_sdX_s\right)+t$$ which is true but is only a very weak version of Itō's formula, which states that $$X_t^2=2\int_0^tX_sdX_s+t$$

Comment: And +1, if only for  the ō in "I hōpe this helps"... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It was introduced to me as "the chain rule of Itō calculus" which I think is a quite elegant description, because it explains it's significance and basic applications. If you know how to calculate the derivatives of your functions $f, g$ then you can derive $f \circ g$.

If you know how to derive a stochastic process $W_t$ and a function $h$, then you can use Itō's formula to derive $h(W_t)$.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, Itō's formula is a type of chain rule. 
Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion (with no drift, starting in 0) Naively, you would guess that the following simple chain rule from analysis holds,
$$
df(W_t)=f'(W_t)dW_t.
$$
However, integrating and taking expectations on both sides would then yield
$$
E[f(W_t)]-f(0)=0\quad\forall t\geq 0
$$
(I used that $E[\int_{0}^{t}g(s)dW_s]=0$ for any adapted process $g(s)$. Intuitively, this holds since in the left-endpoint-rule approximations of the integral, each term has zero expectation because $E[W(s)-W(r)]=0$)
This cannot be true in general. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$ as in your question, this would imply that for any $t\geq 0$ you have $W_t=0$ almost surely, which clearly does not hold.

The above motivates an extra term in the chain rule. The correct form, $\frac{1}{2}f''(W_t)dt$, of this extra term at least makes sense in the above example: Since the Wiener process spreads out, the expected value $E[f(W_t)]$ should be increasing for small $t$ when the second derivative $f''(W_0)$ is positive, and decreasing when it is negative.

To arrive at the exact form of Itō's formula (still not rigorously though) one can use a formal Taylor expansion,
$$
f(W_t)-f(W_0)=f'(W_0)dW_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(W_0)(dW_t)^2+\mathcal{O}(dW_t^3),
$$
together with the intuitive insight that "$(dW_t)^2=dt$" (the variance of $W_t-W_0$ is $t$ by definition of the Wiener process) and "$|dW_t|^r=dt^{r/2}$" for $r>2$, i.e. higher moments are negligible as $dt\to 0$ (again, use that $dW_t$ has normal distribution).

Maybe one can paraphrase the last paragraph as follows:

**Itō's formula is the chain rule that you get when higher order terms in the Taylor expansion of $f(X_t)$ become important due to excessive variations of $X_t$.**

Comment: Your last statement is wrong, at best you can say $|dW_t|^r=O(|dt|^{r/2})$ as $dW_t$ has a normal distribution $N(0,dt)=\sqrt{dt}·N(0,1)$.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it.